# How to create multiple records in FactoryBot by iteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

spec/factories/organisation_groups.rb

```
FactoryBot.define do
  @organisation_groups = [{name: 'WWZY', uuid: '68a0c637'}, {name: 'WCC', uuid: '0a13362e'}, {name: 'ECW', uuid: 'fdcdb1b2'}, {name: 'ZPE', uuid: 'fdcdb1b8'}]
  @organisation_groups.each do |group|
    factory :organisation_group do
      name group[:name]
      uuid group[:uuid]
    end
  end
end
```

I am try to create multiple records using FactoryBot but the issue is I am getting this error :

```
NoMethodError:
  undefined method 'name' in 'organisation_group' factory
  Did you mean? 'name { "WWZY" }'
```

user_spec.rb

```
describe '#organisation_group' do
    before(:each) do
      @organisation_groups = create(:organisation_group)
    end
end
```

Update 1

```
FactoryBot::DuplicateDefinitionError:
  Factory already registered: organisation_group
```

Comment: inside the factory that is inside the loop, it should be `name { group[:name] }`

Comment: @LesNightingill if I do what you suggested then I get the error as stated in update 1 in the question.

Comment: oh yes of course, I missed that error, see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be harder than I thought! After a few missteps, this works:

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :organisation do
    name { 'foo' }
    uuid { '12ab56ef' }
  end
end
```

invoke with

```rb
@organisation_groups = [
  {name: 'WWZY', uuid: '68a0c637'}, 
  {name: 'WCC', uuid: '0a13362e'}, 
  {name: 'ECW', uuid: 'fdcdb1b2'}, 
  {name: 'ZPE', uuid: 'fdcdb1b8'}
]

@organisation_list = @organisation_groups.map do |o| 
  FactoryBot.create(:organisation, name: o[:name], uuid: o[:uuid])
end
```

It's not as clean as you were looking for, but it gets the job done!

Comment: I am getting this error NoMethodError:
  undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @user12763413 try putting the `@organisation_groups` definition in the next line after  `factory :organization_list do`

Comment: It runs now but it just creates one record rather than entire list

pry(#
@ organisation_groups
=> #< OrganisationGroup:0x00007ff4f30a40e8 id: 1, uuid: "12ab56ef", name: "foo">

Comment: @user12763413 it looked like such an easy question!! I finally got something to work, see my new edit.

Comment: Inside your `.map` call, probably `FactoryBot.create(:organisation, o)` will also work and it's a simpler way to do this.